# Found nil despite checking before assigning to variable

Tags: ios, swift

```
if self.mapView.selectedAnnotations?.count != 0 {
    if let selectedAnno = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as? MKAnnotation {
        if (selectedAnno.isKindOfClass(AnnotationTypeOne)) {
            annoType = "a"
        } else if (selectedAnno.isKindOfClass(AnnotationTypeTwo)) {
            annoType = "b"
        }
    }
}
```

Line 2 is returning: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I don't understand why I am seeing this error however as I am checking in the if statement if it is nil before assigning it. I also checked if the array of `selectedAnnotations` is greater than 0 but this doesn't seem to change things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because here:

```
if self.mapView.selectedAnnotations?.count != 0
```

you're checking if `count` is different than zero, but if `selectedAnnotations` is nil, the expression evaluates to `nil`, which is different than zero.

The correct way is:

```
if let annotations = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations {
    if annotations.count != 0 {
        if let selectedAnno = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as? MKAnnotation {
            if (selectedAnno.isKindOfClass(AnnotationTypeOne)) {
                annoType = "a"
            } else if (selectedAnno.isKindOfClass(AnnotationTypeTwo)) {
                annoType = "b"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: `nil != 0` is a legit expression, and evaluates to `true`. Other cases:

```
nil > 0 // false
nil < 0 // true
```

Comment: Side note: this is a great example of where Swift 1.2's new let syntax options would come in handy.